# Where is Elixir 1.2.x for Ubuntu?

Tags: elixir

I was following the newbie instructions and now see this error when I try to run Phoenix

```
Hex was built against against Elixir 1.0.5 and you are running 1.1.0-dev, please run `mix local.hex` to update to a matching version
```

All I did was `sudo apt-get install elixir` from Ubuntu. I feel like I should be on 1.0.5 at this stage, but don't know how to downgrade my Elixir.

**Update:** I have since learnt  that neither of these versions is the latest - I am looking for 1.2.3

Comment: I see no reason to downgrade. You can use version `1.2`, which is, I believe, the last stable version and be happy, just dont forget to update your  `hex`

Comment: Yes, I've since learnt that, but still can't find a way of getting 1.2 easily, without having to compile myself

Comment: You can find it precompiled here -> https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/releases/